# "No Challenges" message Game Center iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I've been actually searching in a lot of sites how to set a game center leaderboard in Objective-C and finally I got the code but it gave me this message when I open Game Center in my app:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8p5L.jpg

I set all the itunes connect stuff and the leaderboard ID is correct so I decided to open a new Xcode project and write just the game center code in Swift and it worked, the leaderboard appeared and work perfectly.

I don't know if it's a problem because of Objective-c or what please can anyone help me what it can be so I don't have to write all the app code from Objective-C to Swift?

Comment: It could be because of where you are implementing the code...

Comment: If you're asking for the leaderboardController.viewState that asks for the Challenges screen, then you're getting exactly what you're asking for.  If you want leaderboards, then you should ask for the viewState requesting that: `GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today, and in searching for a solution, I found your question posted 18 hours ago. My code worked perfectly as of 2 days ago, but when I viewed a leaderboard or achievements page today (any leaderboard with any app, including live games) I saw the "No Challenges" message. I had "Sandbox mode" enabled in the Settings app.

I signed out of Game Center, turned off Sandbox mode, logged back in, and viewed some leaderboards for live games, and they worked properly. I turned Sandbox mode back on and tested my app again, and this time it worked.

Comment: Are you testing your app in iOS simulator or in your iPhone/iPad?